# How to get an open ball in $[0,1]$ that contains $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The definition of bounded we have is that if $X$ is a metric space, $z \in X$, and $X \subseteq X$, then there exists an open ball $B_z(R)$ with finite radius $R$ of $X$ centered at $z$ such that $X \subseteq B_z(R)$.

If $X = [0,1]$, it seems like the largest open ball possible is $(0,1)$ which does not contain $0$ and $1$ so by our definition $[0,1]$ is not bounded, but it obviously is. How can I get $[0,1]$ to be bounded by our definition?

Comment: [0,1]is an open ball.[0,1]=$B_2(1)$

Comment: The subset $[0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$, it is for example a ball of radius $2$ is this space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If $X=[0,1]$, it seems like the largest open ball possible is $(0,1)$ …

And this is what is false. *Any* open ball of *any* radius in a metric space $X$ is by definition considered, well, as an open ball in it, regardless of how the ball or $X$ itself look like to us.

The definition of an open ball $B_z(R)$ in a metric space $X = (X,d)$ is 
$$B_z(R) = \{x ∈ X;~d(x,z) < R\}.$$
(Although most people swap the places of $z$ and $R$ and write “$B_R(z)$” instead.)

Note that by definition, the ball only consist of points “$x ∈ X$” with a certain property.

Thus, the $2$-ball at $0$ *in $X = [0..1]$* e.g. is by definition $B_0(R) = \{x ∈ [0..1];~|x-0| < 2\}$. What points $x ∈ [0..1]$ satisfy $|x| < 2$?

Comment: What I am confused about is how you can claim a $2$-ball exists in the first place, since the number $2 \not\in X$, so doesn't that mean the number $2$ doesn't "exist" in our space so we aren't allowed to consider it in the first place?

Comment: @user130018, the *radius* isn't an element of the *space*.

Comment: For any *positive real number* $R ∈ (0..∞)$ and any *point* $z ∈ X$, the ball $B_R(z)$ is defined. The radius is always taken to be a positive real number.